# Make multiple Formik-fields required with Yup if any of them have a value

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, validation, yup

I have a Formik-form which is validated with Yup. My problem is that all three fields, let's call them `Field1`, `Field2`, and `Field3` (all are Strings), are optional by default, but all of them are required if any of them are filled out.

What would my validationSchema look like to make this work

I already have a starting-point with two other fields where if one is filled out the other is not required anymore, but one of them must be filled out at all times, it looks like this:

```
field4: Yup.string()
            .ensure()
            .when('field5', {
                is: '',
                then: Yup.string().required('Please fill out Field4 or Field5'),
            }),
field5: Yup.string()
            .ensure()
            .when('field4', {
                is: '',
                then: Yup.string().required(''),
            }),
```

Comment: What was your attempt at solving this and what were the issues you faced?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In `yup` you can check depending on other values using `when` as you did with `field4` and `field5`. And you can actually listen to more than one field at the same time.

You have to be careful with cyclic dependencies

There is some solution using the param noSortEdges but there is not much documentation around it. You can find a test of it working [here](https://github.com/jquense/yup/blob/master@%7B2017-01-20%7D/test/object.js#L609).

So a possible solution would be:

```js
const schema = yup.object().shape(
  {
    field1: yup.string().when(["field2", "field3"], {
      is: (a, b) => a !== undefined || b !== undefined,
      then: yup.string().required("Please fill out Field1, Field2 or Field3")
    }),
    field2: yup.string().when(["field1", "field3"], {
      is: (a, b) => a !== undefined || b !== undefined,
      then: yup.string().required("Please fill out Field1, Field2 or Field3")
    }),
    field3: yup.string().when(["field1", "field2"], {
      is: (a, b) => a !== undefined || b !== undefined,
      then: yup.string().required("Please fill out Field1, Field2 or Field3")
    })
  },
  [["field1", "field2"], ["field1", "field3"], ["field2", "field3"]]
);
```

Comment: Your answer helped me a lot, just a small edition, checking for  `a !== ""` still resulted in the field being required, even if there was no value in it. Checking instead for `a !== undefined`seems to be working instead

Comment: Great! I edited the answer with `undefined`.